# Fine-tuning / Retraining transferred learning model with an additional image set

Tags: tensorflow

Using the `retrain.py` script provided in the tensorflow source example, I've retrained the top layer of the `inception-v3` model to be able to classify the flower set (provided image set of the 5 flowers).

What I am trying to do now, is to take the new transferred learning model (TL-model), and expand upon it with two new sets of flowers without having to completely retrain the entire model. (5 categories of flowers -> 7 categories of flowers)

My approaches:

- Replacing the base model (`inception-v3`) with the TL-model and attempting to build of that on startup. This results in various duplicates of tensors and ops at the top layer and the loss of the softmax subgraph.
- Loading in meta graphs of the TL-model. This approach seemingly works great if I only needed to add new images to the previous categories of flowers that were already present in the model. Adding a new category breaks this approach and causes it to crash out as there are tensor size differences between the meta graph and new model to be trained.
- Restoring checkpoints, resulted in the same problem as the meta graphs.

I feel like I am fundamentally missing something and approaching this problem from the wrong direction. Any insight at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't easy without doing some 'brain surgery' on the model structure. I don't have a great answer, since I've never done this myself, but in theory you should be able to restore the old five-category fully-connected layer into a new extended seven-category version, and then rerun the training.

Comment: @PeteWarden - could you convert your comment to an answer, since it seems to be the best answer thus found?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(Converted from a comment to an answer, per @dga's request)

Unfortunately this isn't easy without doing some 'brain surgery' on the model structure. I don't have a great answer, since I've never done this myself, but in theory you should be able to restore the old five-category fully-connected layer into a new extended seven-category version, and then rerun the training